# Closed form for:$I(j) = \int_0^1 \dfrac{\cos{(\pi j x/2)}}{\sin{(\frac{\pi}{4}(1-x))}} \log{\Big( \frac{\sin{\pi /4}}{\sin{\pi x/4}} \Big)}dx$?

Tags: integration, logarithms, trigonometric-integrals

Any hints on this following type of integral:
  $$I(j) = \int_0^1 \dfrac{\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2} j x)}}{\sin{(\frac{\pi}{4}(1-x))}} \log{\Big( \frac{\sin{(\frac{\pi}{4})}}{\sin{(\frac{\pi x}{4})}} \Big)}dx,$$

where $j \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. For odd $j$'s Mathematica has no trouble finding both analytic and numerical solution. For even ones it complains about singularities.

Example solutions found by Mathematica:
$$ I(1) = -\dfrac{2 \sqrt{2} (-2 + \log{(8 (\tan{(\frac{\pi}{8})})^2})}{\pi}$$

$$I(3) = \dfrac{2 (720 - 542 \sqrt{2} + 765 \sqrt{2} \log{2} + 
   510 \sqrt{2} \log{(\tan{\frac{\pi}{8})}}}{225 \pi}$$

$$ I(5) = - \dfrac{420000 - 448804 \sqrt{2} + 655830 \sqrt{2} \log{2} + 
 437220 \sqrt{2} \log{(\tan{\frac{\pi}{8}}})}{99225 \pi} $$

I'm interested only in odd $j$ cases.

Obviously there exists a closed form solution to this integral given in terms of a product or a sum that depends on the $j$ variable. Also asymptotic solution for $j \rightarrow \infty$ looks something like $\sim 1/j$ judging from numerics.

My attempts so far:

- Integration by parts (singularity problems)
- Using identity as in [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) (results in sums over hypergeometric functions)
- Using Feynmanesque trick knowing that $ \partial_{x} a^x = a^{x} \ln{(a)}$ as in [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1146411/529452) (a lot of seemingly non-trivial trigonometric integrals)

Bottom line question is:
*Is there a simple closed form solution for this integral for general odd $j$?*

Any help would be welcome,

sofista137

Comment: for j odd consider integration by parts.

Comment: I have obtained the asymptotic solution to my problem via steepest descend approximation. I will post its as soon as I can.